# HTTP3 version with python-requests

Tags: python-requests, http3

I need to send requests with http3 support for parsing the site (only http/3 requests are accepted). I found one single python module "http3", but now it is not supported by the developer and there is no possibility to set "proxies" parameter in the request.

Is it possible to provide support for http/3 version of requests with "requests" library? Or is there a similar module or solution?

Comment: Check out aioquic at https://github.com/aiortc/aioquic